# Casting error with a native SQL query JPA Eclipse Link

Tags: sql, jpa

I'm working with JPA implemented with EclipseLink. I need to do a native SQL query about my MRAEmpleado entity.

This is my code:

```
    private List<MRAProyecto> ordenarProyectos (){
      Query q = em.createNativeQuery("Select *From MRAProyecto ORDER BY PROY_ID");
       return (List<MRAProyecto>)q.getResultList();
    }
        List<MRAProyecto> consultaProyectos = startup.ordenarProyectos();
        System.out.println("Lista de proyectos ordenados por su identificador");
         for (MRAProyecto proyecto:(List<MRAProyecto>)consultaProyectos){

             System.out.println(proyecto.toString());
        }
```

but This error is launched when I execute my application:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to entity.MRAProyecto
at Startup.main(Startup.java:39)
```

I have tried with all casting posibilities, but the cast error doesn't dissapear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following call to do the parse.

Query     createNativeQuery(java.lang.String sqlString, java.lang.Class resultClass)
          Create an instance of Query for executing a native SQL query.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNativeQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%29

You need to define in resultSetClass the entitiy you want to retrieve

Comment: Where can I define the entity? I don't understand very well, I have done System.out.println(q.getResultList().get(0).getClass()); and this print class [Ljava.lang.Object; Don't should be MRAProyecto??

Comment: Query q = em.createNativeQuery("Select *From MRAProyecto ORDER BY PROY_ID");                                                     use  Query q = em.createNativeQuery("Select *From MRAProyecto ORDER BY PROY_ID", MRAProyecto );                                                 Read this http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/vasiliev-jpql-087123.html in the section Utilizing Native SQL Queries.                  But basically you should use a second parameter that define the fully qualified entity class

Comment: It isn't possible, compiler give me one error. I add a snapshot:http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/800x600q90/203/zbcj.jpg

Comment: It should be MRAProyecto.class as the second param need Class clazz.    em.createNativeQuery("Select *From MRAProyecto ORDER BY PROY_ID", MRAProyecto.class )